# Problem in the operation "Add xy Coordinate" in ArcGIS10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, features

I have a problem in the operation "Add xy Coordinate" in ArcGIS10.
For a point shp theme with  many point objects I did “ArcToolboox - Data management- Features- Add xy Coordinate”,  after that the program informed that operation was created correctly, but the meanings of all point objects in the created fields POINT_X and POINT_Y – are zero (0).

What can be a reason of this error? Maybe something related with Workspace?

Comment: Did you get an error?  Please look in Geoprcessing --> Current Session and tell us what it says there.  You can also try running it again but make sure you are not editing or have ArcCatalog opened - also all instances of ArcMap should be closed (even those that crashed but where process is still opened)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what might caused it but you may try following to get coordinates in your attribute table:

1. Add a new double field and call it coor_x
2. Right click on field and pick calculate geometry.
3. Add another new double field and call it coor_y
4. Right click on field and pick calculate geometry.

Let us know if you still have zero values on the coordinates.

Comment: Thank you! Your method works, I’ve got the coordinates!

Also I found the answer for my question . The shp theme must be in the desired projection for the coordinate calculating (I need metres, so – I put it in the UTM projection). And the second reason: I didn’t choose the "XY Resolution and Tolerance" in the Environment settings (metres in my case).

Comment: Good to hear you've sorted it out.